# CodingKey not found from a different struct during decoding

Tags: json, swift, codable

I am trying to use a parsed date string (`dateString`) from the `Datum` struct to build a new Date object in the `AzimuthAtDate` class...

```
{
    "11": [{
        "name": "Sun",
        "date": "2021-01-26",
        "rising": [{
            "coord": "113.6681",
            "hour": "07:16"
        }],
        "transit-sup": [{
            "coord": "32.4711",
            "hour": "12:16"
        }],
        "setting": [{
            "coord": "246.4743",
            "hour": "17:17"
        }]
    }]
}
```

```
struct Datum: Codable, CustomStringConvertible {

    let name: String
    let dateString: String
    let isoDate: Date?
    let rising: [AzimuthAtDate]
    let transit: [ElevationAtDate]
    let setting: [AzimuthAtDate]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case dateString = "date"
        case isoDate
        case rising = "rising"
        case transit = "transit-sup"
        case setting = "setting"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let con = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try con.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.dateString = try con.decode(String.self, forKey: .dateString)
        self.isoDate = try con.decode(Date.self, forKey: .dateString)
        self.rising = decodeAzimuthAtDate(decoder: decoder, key: .rising)
        self.transit = decodeElevationAtDate(decoder: decoder, key: .transit)
        self.setting = decodeAzimuthAtDate(decoder: decoder, key: .setting)
    }
}
```

```
class CoordHour: Codable {
    let coord: String
    let hour: String
    var isoDate: Date?
    init(coord: String, hour: String, isoDate: Date?) {
        self.coord = coord
        self.hour = hour
        self.isoDate = isoDate
    }
}
```

But in trying to access a key from `Datum.CodingKeys` from within `AzimuthAtDate`, `datumContainer` has no keys. And so I get an error like this:
`keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "date", intValue: nil) ... debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"date\", intValue: nil) (\"date\").", underlyingError: nil))`

```
class AzimuthAtDate: CoordHour {
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let coordHourContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CoordHour.CodingKeys.self)
        let coord = try coordHourContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .coord)
        let hour = try coordHourContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .hour)
        
        print("coord:\(coord) - hour:\(hour)") // prints correct info
        
        let datumContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Datum.CodingKeys.self)

        print("datumContainer keys:\(datumContainer.allKeys)") // shows []
        
        let dateString = try datumContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .dateString)
        print("dateString:\(dateString)")
        
        let currentTZ = TimeZone.currentOffsetFromUTCString
        let isoDateString = "\(dateString)T\(hour)\(currentTZ)"
        let isoDate = DateFormatter.Iso.date(from: isoDateString)
        
        super.init(coord: coord, hour: hour, isoDate: isoDate)
    }
}
```

In the `AzimuthAtDate` class, how can I get access to `Datum.dateString` key so I can use its value to form `isoDate`?

```
func decodeAzimuthAtDate(decoder: Decoder, key: Datum.CodingKeys) -> [AzimuthAtDate] {
    var result = [AzimuthAtDate]()
    do {
        let con = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Datum.CodingKeys.self)
        if let az = try con.decode([AzimuthAtDate]?.self, forKey: key)?.first {
            result.append(az)
        }
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: It seems that your JSON doesn't have a key `date`, so how are you supposed to find a value non existing? Could you show the JSON that you are using?

Comment: I added the JSON. I have been able to parse this without trouble until I decided to separate into two types of `coord/hour` pairs by creating the `CoordHour` class from which `AzimuthAtDate` and `ElevationAtDate` inherit.

Comment: The code is confusing. For example what are those custom methods like `decodeAzimuthAtDate`?

Comment: Now I understand. You are trying go get parent container `"date": "2021-01-26"` but I don't think it works like that. I think you don't see it when `init(from decoder:)` is called in `AzimuthAtDate`. When you call `let datumContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Datum.CodingKeys.self)`, you are with subJSON:  `{"coord": "246.4743", "hour": "17:17"}`.

Comment: I am really just trying to turn "hour" into an actual iso date in the correct time zone, it's gotten confusing to me since I am new to JSON decoding and each coord/hour item is formed as an array even though there is only ever a single pair. It has gotten messy and I'm not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: @Larme I can see this what you mean now. Do you have any suggestion for how to set it up so "date" and "hour" can be combined into a Date type?

Comment: Forget decoding and json. Ask yourself how _any_ inner struct would get a property of an outer struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ignore the decoding and JSON and think about the problem in more general terms. How would an inner struct know anything the outer struct that holds it as a property?

For example, what would have to happen here:

```
struct InnerStruct {
    func test() {
        // ?
    }
}
struct OuterStruct {
    let inner = InnerStruct()
    let other = "howdy"
}
```

... in order for a call to `inner`'s `test()` to print `"howdy"`? Clearly the InnerStruct that is `inner` needs a *reference* to the OuterStruct that is holding it. Something like this:

```
struct InnerStruct {
    weak var container : OuterStruct?
    func test() {
        print(self.container?.other)
    }
}
class OuterStruct {
    var inner = InnerStruct()
    let other = "howdy"
    init() {
        self.inner.container = self
    }
}
let outerStruct = OuterStruct()
outerStruct.inner.test()
```

So that is the sort of thing you would need to do. Your inner types need a property that is a reference to their container so that they can "see" that date, and you need to set that reference when everything else is configured. Or else you could even just use the outer date to set a property of the inner types. But you can't do that as part of decoding; it has to be done after everything is configured.

Here's a simple example of one possibility, based on your data (this is playground code):

```
let json = """
{
    "11": [{
        "name": "Sun",
        "date": "2021-01-26",
        "rising": [{
            "coord": "113.6681",
            "hour": "07:16"
        }],
        "transit-sup": [{
            "coord": "32.4711",
            "hour": "12:16"
        }],
        "setting": [{
            "coord": "246.4743",
            "hour": "17:17"
        }]
    }]
}
"""

let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8)

class Inner: Decodable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let coord : String
    let hour : String
    var outerDate : String?
    var description : String {
        return (self.coord + ";" + self.hour + ";" + (self.outerDate ?? ""))
    }
}
struct Outer: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let date: String
    let rising: [Inner]
    let transitsup: [Inner]
    let setting: [Inner]
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case date
        case rising
        case transitsup = "transit-sup"
        case setting
    }
}
struct Main: Decodable {
    let x: [Outer]
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case x = "11"
    }
}
let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Main.self, from: jsonData!)
let outers = result.x
for anOuter in outers {
    let date = anOuter.date
    for anInner in anOuter.rising {
        anInner.outerDate = date
    }
    for anInner in anOuter.setting {
        anInner.outerDate = date
    }
    for anInner in anOuter.transitsup {
        anInner.outerDate = date
    }
}
print(outers)
```

As you can see, when we are done, every Inner knows its container's `date`. So it could then proceed to calculate the date-time.

Comment: Added actual possible example of general approach.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation. When I see how simple this can be I don't know how I ended up with such a mess.